# Identifying if a user is in building or shopping mall using GPS or WiFi data

Tags: gps, android, geolocation, mobile, wifi

I am trying to understand if there is a logic to see if a user is in a shopping mall or a building or outside using GPS or WiFi data captured from a mobile phone.

Is there a logic to check?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works